# How can I get the size of an external image in SSRS for aligning the image within a table cell?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm currently attempting to dynamically offset an image in a table cell within Visual Studio.

Here's what my report looks like currently when generated:

[image: No offset here]

The problem I would like to deal with is the extra space beneath each image within the table.

I have the images currently with the "Sizing" property set to **FitProportional**

The table cell size is a hard requirement and I cannot alter this as it is meant to be printed eventually with very specific proportions.

My problem is that I need to have the images vertically aligned in the center of the cell. I have tried something like mentioned here: http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathaneccles/2014/04/15/ssrs-right-and-centre-align-images-in-a-table as an attempt to align it verically, but I believe the issue is in how I try to fetch the size of the image in order to calculate how much the offset would be.

The expression I had been experimenting with to no avail was in the top offset property, which I set to:

```
=CSTR(round((400 - (round((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(System.Convert.FromBase64String(ReportItems!Image1.Value), Byte()))).Width*0.75) / ((System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(System.Convert.FromBase64String(ReportItems!Image1.Value), Byte()))).Height*0.75)/330),0))) / 2, 0)) + "pt"
```

I believe the issue is that the images used are external, and their paths don't fit whatever format is needed for the function above. I'm not sure how to get around this however.

Here is the image properties:

[image: image properties]

I've also tried using `Parameters!Inventory.Value &  Fields!PhotoFileName.Value` as the argument within the FromBase64String function, to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.